# .py Files Aren't Opening Correctly

Tags: python

I am Writing The Code That You Can See Under That Article On IDLE It Correctly Works But When I Save The Code As A `.py` File It Doesn't Opens How I Can Open A `.py` File Correctly?

```
import random
from random import randint
random.randint(111111111, 999999999)
```

(Problem Solved I Erase The The Code That You Can See Under That Article And It Works)

```
from random import randint
```

Comment: **It Doesn't Opens** - What do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Would you like to run it? Run it from command line. Open? Probably right-click. Please provide more details and stop writing Camel Case.

Comment: Arash Hatami  I mean When I Double Click On .py File Nothing Just Happens

Comment: M. Volf Man I Have Run It On Command Line So It's Works But It Never Works As A .py File And I'll Never Stop Writing Like That

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are attempting to open a .py file by double clicking on it, you need to have the version of python you want to run it with added to your PATH. Also you need the .py file extension associated with the Python application.

The other way to do this is to have all .py files opened with Idle, Pycharm, Sublime Text, etc (Whatever IDE you sue to write it). This wont automatically run the file however, it will open it in an editable state in your IDE.

Lastly, as it relates to the code you provided, importing randint() is not necessary as you've already imported the entire random module.

Comment: Thanks I Was Downloaded Python On Visual Studio(.)I'll Download It in Original Site With Path Thanks (A)gain

Comment: Thanks PATH Worked